# IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer#Pause

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I uploaded my app at google console and in prelaunch report , in 2 devices only, there was this issue *java.lang.IllegalStateException*

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: com.wolframite.manos.crack_the_code, PID: 11744
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
at com.wolframite.manos.crack_the_code.Music$1.onReceive(Music.java:36)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:311)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:47)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:120)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:142)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:134)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:74)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:9)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.a(Tap.java:19)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.b(Tap.java:2)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:78)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:94)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I don't know what to do.
What is this issue and what more do I need to upload to help solve this.

The music class which is used to play music in the app and receives a broadcast when app goes in background to stop music and when app goes in foreground to resume it where line 36 is player.pause() :

```
public class Music extends Service {
private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
public void onCreate() {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    player.setLooping(true);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(StateReceiver, new IntentFilter("status"));

}
private final BroadcastReceiver StateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
        if (parseInt(String.valueOf(status)) == 0) {
            player.pause();
        } else if (parseInt(String.valueOf(status)) == 1) {
            if (player != null)
                player.start();
            else {
                player = MediaPlayer.create(Music.this, R.raw.music);
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.start();
            }
        } else if(player != null){
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }

    }
};
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(StateReceiver);
    stopSelf();
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: what is at Music.java:36 ?

Comment: In 36 is `player.pause()` , player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

Comment: Where is this line placed (in OnCreate?)? Also, add all relevant code in question

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory. There is a point in your `com.wolframite.manos.crack_the_code.Music` at line 36 where, probably in response to a broadcast, you pause a `MusicPlayer` that has not been initialized  (i.e. `setDataSource` has not been called or something like that). Post the code for that class, or if it is too large, the code for the method in which that call is made.

Comment: @LeoAso Posted the code

Comment: Try to change the `player.pause()` to `if (player.isPlaying()) { player.pause() }` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @LeoAso Will do but it will take some time for pre launch report results

Comment: @LeoAso I just received the results and the problem persist

Comment: You also can try to set MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener and not call pause() or isPlaying() when the player is not prepared yet.

Comment: @algrid what do u mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to avoid these type of errors you can create a utility class which acts as a secure wrapper around the `MediaPlayer` methods which sometimes throw unexpected exception and crash your app.

I have used code in a class called `MediaPlayerUtils` like the example below to avoid these types of behaviours and add an extra layer of safety to my apps:

```
public static void pause(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(MediaPlayerUtil.class.getName(),
                    String.format("Failed to stop media player: %s", e));
        }
    }
}
```

You then have to use instead of:

```
player.pause(); // not safe
```

this code:

```
MediaPlayerUtils.pause(player);  // safe
```

You can add similar methods to the for `MediaPlayer.stop()`, like e.g:;

```
public static void stop(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            resetRelease(mediaPlayer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MediaPlayerUtil.class.getName(),
                    String.format("Failed to stop media player: %s", e));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full class?